# Is it possible to make all files in a dir be always created as symlinks to /dev/null or ignore all writes to them in other way?

Tags: symbolic-link, logs, tmpfs

I always redirect unneeded logs that are always stored under one name to `/dev/null` by symlinking. But some applications create directories with files named, for example, by date. I do not want to store these logs anywhere (not even in `tmpfs`) but still make the application think it's dumping the contents there, not throwing any errors on a write. Is there a way to do it?

For example with VirtualBox configured to store VMs in `~/.virtualbox` it creates `~/.virtualbox/VM/Logs/` directories that I don't want to store.

Comment: Would not a simple sh/bash script wiping given directories clean at regular intervals be suitable ?

Comment: It's still storing to disk/RAM and wearing disk or taking the precious RAM space, I woundn't post this question if that was suitable. But I don't yet know if there is a suitable solution existing at all.

Comment: How big are these log files? Too much to store them on a tmpfs for a few minutes and then wiping them periodically?

Comment: Realistically, I believe there is no way to do exactly, what you describe, except with a specialised file system or a hook on the `open(2)` function. Since this a question directed at *nix fundamentals, I suggest you migrate it to [Unix.SE].

Comment: For VBox case, you may disable logs as mentioned here https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11988

Comment: Essentially it's a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project allows creating such directories:

https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs